# Internal timestamp field is not changed after partial update

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

we have a really strange phenomenon with our team's Cosmos DB.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/databases#:%7E:text=system%2Dgenerated%20identifier.-,_ts,-It%20is%20a), every document in cosmos DB has a timestamp property named `_ts` which is updated using Azure CosmosDB core functionality every time a document is created/updated (even partial update).

We have modeled our code to use this field as a last update time field, and every time we update/create a document, we expect this field to change accordingly.

Lately, we've started to see a strange phenomenon on which for some documents that we updated using patch operation (partial update) - the `_ts` field hasn't been changed at all.
It's important to mention that it happens for some and not for all the documents we patch which makes it even stranger.

For example, we've created a document with some unique id and updated it multiple times using patch operations.
It turned out that the timestamp value of the _ts field had kept as it was when we created the document

We are doing the updates using a .net core job deployed in a k8s cluster with the latest .net core SDK Nuget version of CosmosDB, and we have no idea how to move forward from here.

Will appreciate your assistance.

Edit: An example for the code I use:

```
var patchOperations = new List<PatchOperation>();
patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Replace($"/{nameof(DeploymentState)}", DeploymentState.PendingRemoval));
patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Replace($"/{nameof(ExecutionId)}", executionId));
container.PatchItemAsync<State>(modelId, new PartitionKey(partitionKey), patchOperations, cancellationToken: ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: What is the time between the document creation and the updates? Is it in the order of seconds or minutes or more?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta - days... Looks like it doesn't get changed at all from its creation time value

Comment: Can you add code examples of the operations you are performing?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Added code example in the question

Comment: I have confirmed this behaviour just now using the latest SDKs.  I patch a property on the document in Cosmos and the `_ts` value IS NOT updated.  Not sure if this is by design or a bug

Comment: I have raised a bug in GitHub - https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/3617